# PIXI js water drop animation speeding up on each ripple event

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

First time using [PixiJS](https://www.pixijs.com/) and looking to create a background to my web page whereby the user can click it and a water ripple appears centered on the click which expands co-centrically from there.

It works perfectly on the first click, but subsequent clicks the "co-centric expansion" animation speeds up, so by click 5 it is really fast.

I cannot find how to keep it at the same speed. Additionally,  noticed that the code runs for more iterations than needed as the ripple has disappeared from the page. Any help is appreciated!

Here's my code (sorry it is so long):

HTML / Blade Template:

```
 <div
    id="water-ripples"
    class="relative bg-cover h-vhscreen flex flex-col justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8"
    style="background-image: url({{ env('AWS_STATIC_BUCKET_URL') . '/images/water.jpg' }});"
>
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
window.moment = require('moment');

/**
 * Set up last code to run when page assembled
 */
let app = null
let stage = null
let renderer = null
let ripples = []
let sprite = null

$(document).ready(function() {

    app = new PIXI.Application({
        antialias: true,
        transparent: true,
        resolution: 1,
    })

    // setup ticker
    let ticker = new PIXI.Ticker();
    ticker.add(() => {
        renderer.render(stage);
    }, PIXI.UPDATE_PRIORITY.LOW);
    ticker.start();

    renderer = app.renderer
    renderer.autoResize = true
    renderer.view.style.position = "fixed";
    renderer.view.style.top = 0;
    renderer.view.style.left = 0;
    renderer.view.style.zIndex = 1;
    renderer.view.style.display = "block";
    renderer.autoResize = true
    renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    ripples = [];

    stage = app.stage;
    stage.interactive = true

    document.getElementById('water-ripples').appendChild(app.renderer.view)

    // load assets
    let resources = {
        waterRippleImage: aws_static_bucket_url + '/images/water.jpg',
        waterRippleMap: aws_static_bucket_url + '/images/water_map.png',
    };

    Object.keys(resources).forEach(k => {
        app.loader.add(k, resources[k])
    })

    app.loader.load(setup);

    ticker.add(function(delta) {
        for(var i = 0; i < ripples.length; i++) {
            ripples[i].update();
        }
    });
});

function setup() {
    // background
    let bg = new PIXI.Sprite(app.loader.resources.waterRippleImage.texture);

    bg.anchor.set(0.5);
    bg.scale.set(0.9);
    bg.position.set(renderer.view.width / 2, renderer.view.height / 2);
    stage.addChild(bg);

    // add new ripple each time mouse is clicked
    renderer.view.addEventListener('mousedown', ev => {
        ripples.push(new Ripple(ev.clientX, ev.clientY));
        stage.filters = ripples.map(function(f) { return f.filter; });
    }, false);

    // add new ripple each time screen is touched
    renderer.view.addEventListener('touchstart', ev => {
        ripples.push(new Ripple(ev.clientX, ev.clientY));
        stage.filters = ripples.map(function(f) { return f.filter; });
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        bg.position.set(renderer.view.width / 2, renderer.view.height / 2);
    })

    window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
        // Clear Out Old Ripples
        ripples = ripples.filter(r => {
            return (moment.now() - 1000) < r.startTime
        })
    })

    window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        // Clear Out Old Ripples
        ripples = ripples.filter(r => {
            return (moment.now() - 1000) < r.startTime
        })
    })
}

function Ripple(x, y) {
    // sprite
    sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(app.loader.resources.waterRippleMap.texture);

    sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
    sprite.position.set(x, y);
    sprite.scale.set(0.1);
    stage.addChild(sprite);

    // filter
    this.filter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(sprite);
    this.startTime = moment.now()
}

Ripple.prototype.update = function() {
    sprite.scale.x += 0.025;
    sprite.scale.y += 0.025;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sprite in the Ripple class is the issue.  It should be assigned to `this.sprite`, rather than a global variable sprite.  As it is, when you iterate over the ripples, you're incrementing scale N times, where N is the number of ripples.

Comment: Hi @Irongaze.com you rock! Thanks! Fixed it.